# Flexbox align items horizontally on one row

Tags: html, sass, flexbox, shopify

We use Shopify and in the past a dev has created a custom tabs class for us. Unfortunately, he's no longer with us and I'm trying to modify it myself - without success. I'm a complete noob when it comes to flexbox & scss.

Here's the scss:

```
 ul.tabbies {
  @extend %block;
  @include overflow-touch;
  @extend %unselectable;
  @include flexbox();
  @include flex-grow(1);
  @include flex-shrink(0);
  @include justify-content(flex-start);
  @include align-items(stretch);

  border-bottom-color: $tabs-border-bottom-color;
  border-bottom-style: $tabs-border-bottom-style;
  border-bottom-width: $tabs-border-bottom-width;

  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  a {
    height: calc(100% + 1px);
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  
  
  a {
    @include align-items(center);
    border-bottom-color: $tabs-border-bottom-color;
    border-bottom-style: $tabs-border-bottom-style;
    border-bottom-width: $tabs-border-bottom-width;
    color: $tabs-link-color;
    @include flexbox();
    @include justify-content(center);
    margin-bottom: -#{$tabs-border-bottom-width};
    padding: $tabs-link-padding;
    padding-left: 0;
    vertical-align: top;

    &:hover {
      border-bottom-color: $tabs-link-hover-border-bottom-color;
      color: $tabs-link-hover-color;
    }
  }

  li {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0.25em;
    width: min-intrinsic;
    width: -webkit-min-content;
    width: -moz-min-content;
    width: min-content;
    display: table-caption;
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: min-content;

    &.active,
    &.is-active {
      a {
        border-bottom-color: $tabs-link-active-border-bottom-color;
        color: $tabs-link-active-color;
      }
    }

    a.active,
    a.is-active {
      border-bottom-color: $tabs-link-active-border-bottom-color;
      color: $tabs-link-active-color;

      * {
        color: $tabs-link-active-color;// Used to ensure headings get proper color set
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using html on the page to hard-code the tab structure e.g.

```
<!--Start tab labels-->
<ul class="tabbies">
<li><a class="active" href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2001-alina-cojocaru">2001</a></li>
<li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2002-deborah-bull">2002</a></li>
<li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2003-gemma-bond">2003</a></li>
<li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2004-caroline-duprot">2004</a></li>
<li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2005-roberto-bolle">2005</a></li>
<li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2006-zoe-anderson">2006</a></li>
<li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2007-johanna-adams">2007</a></li>
<li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2008-deborah-bull">2008</a></li>
<li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2009-federico-bonelli">2009</a></li>
<li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2010-vanessa-fenton">2010</a></li>
<li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2011-camille-bracher">2011-2020</a></li>
<li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2020-jessica-clarke">2020-2030</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="tabbies">
<li><a class="active" href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2001-alina-cojocaru">Alina Cojocaru</a></li>
<li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2001-gailene-stock">Gailene Stock</a></li>
<li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2001-hubert-essakow">Hubert Essakow</a></li>
<li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2001-jenny-tattersall">Jenny Tattersall</a></li>
<li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2001-jenny-tattersall">Tom Sapsford</a></li>
</ul>
<!--End tab labels-->
```

Here's a link to the page https://balletassociation.co.uk/pages/reports-2001-alina-cojocaru

What I'm trying to achieve is the top row all on a single line i.e. 2011-2020, 2021-2030 and not displayed on top of each other.
The bottom row is correct, with the dancer's name on two rows.

Is it possible to do this? If so, can you point me in the right direction as everything I've tried so far has failed.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `flex-wrap` to `nowrap`. Although, note that currently your flexbox rows only wrap when the browser size is smaller than the minimum width of all of the elements anyways.

[image: How your site currently renders when the min size is smaller and forces a wrap.]

How your site currently renders when the min size is smaller and forces a wrap.

[image: As you can see, with flex-wrap set to no-wrap, you will get overflow/unreachable elements in your flexbox.]

As you can see, with flex-wrap set to no-wrap, you will get overflow/unreachable elements in your flexbox.

Comment: Thank you @loomy! Unfortunately, changing to flex-wrap: no-wrap; didn't work. All it did was increase the font size of the items. I'm thinking that Shopify may have some other code which is influencing it. I may have to find a Shopify developer who more familiar with how it works.

Comment: I made a mistake when I replied and put a dash in nowrap. Use "flex-wrap: nowrap" instead. I corrected my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this
copy this code into new project to see the result

it's working for me

```css
// if use scss use this code
// .tabbies {
//     display: flex;
//     width: 90%;
//     .active {
//         color: black;
//     }
//     li {
//         list-style: none;
//         width: 80px;
//         padding-left: 15px;
//         a {
//             text-decoration: none;
//             color: gray;
//             font-size: 20px;
//             margin-right: 15%;
//         }
//     }
// }

// if use css use this code
.tabbies {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 90%;
}

.tabbies .active {
  color: black;
}

.tabbies li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 80px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.tabbies li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<!--Start tab labels-->
<ul class="tabbies">
    <li><a class="active" href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2001-alina-cojocaru">2001</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2002-deborah-bull">2002</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2003-gemma-bond">2003</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2004-caroline-duprot">2004</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2005-roberto-bolle">2005</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2006-zoe-anderson">2006</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2007-johanna-adams">2007</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2008-deborah-bull">2008</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2009-federico-bonelli">2009</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2010-vanessa-fenton">2010</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2011-camille-bracher">2011-2020</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2020-jessica-clarke">2020-2030</a></li>
</ul>
<hr />
<ul class="tabbies">
    <li><a class="active" href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2001-alina-cojocaru">Alina Cojocaru</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2001-gailene-stock">Gailene Stock</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2001-hubert-essakow">Hubert Essakow</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2001-jenny-tattersall">Jenny Tattersall</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://balletassociation.myshopify.com/pages/reports-2001-jenny-tattersall">Tom Sapsford</a></li>
</ul>
<hr />
<!--End tab labels-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @yassine albi! I added the scss code block and updated the html on the page. Unfortunately, it didn't work. All it did was increase the font size of the items. I'm thinking that Shopify may have some other code which is influencing it. I may have to find a Shopify developer who more familiar with how it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).